# iOS objective c retrieving data from server NSUrl not able to access to global variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurl

hi I am new to iOS and I am  giving request to server and getting top to the mobile number and through request reply I am able to get the otp but when I print the data out of the seesion which is initialised inside block I am getting null

this is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>. 
@interface OtpViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *str;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *tmp;
@property(weak,nonatomic) NSString *requestReply ;
@end
```

this is my url request block in .m file

```
- (IBAction)submitb:(id)sender
{
if (_mobiletf.text && _mobiletf.text.length >0 )
{
    /* not empty - do something */
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"phone=%@",_mobiletf.text];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    //  Next up, we read the postData's length, so we can pass it along in the request.
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    // Now that we have what we'd like to post, we can create an NSMutableURLRequest, and include our postData
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sitesandflats.com/send_otp.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSLog(@"the data Details is %@", post);
    //   And finally, we can send our request, and read the reply by creating a new NSURLSession:
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // this is json string
         //   NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
            NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);
            self.tmp=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"otp"] ;
            self.str=self.tmp;
            NSLog(@"tmp storage inside block:%@",self.tmp);

            [self performSelector:@selector(updateStatus) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
           // NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);

            //self.tmp=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"otp"] ;
            //self.str=self.tmp;
            //NSLog(@"tmp storage inside block:%@",self.tmp);
    }] resume];
    //self.str=self.tmp;
    NSLog(@" storage:%@",self.str);
    NSLog(@"tmp storage:%@",self.tmp);
    [ self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b1" sender:self];

}
else
{
    /* what ever */
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
        message:@"Please check your input!!."
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}

-(void)updateStatus{
NSLog(@" storage:%@",self.str);
NSLog(@"tmp storage:%@",self.tmp);
 // [ self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b1" sender:self];


}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(nullable    id)sender
{
VerifyViewController *loadCtr = (VerifyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
loadCtr.otpStr =self.tmp;
loadCtr.mobileStr = _mobiletf.text;

}
```

this is my print log

```
 2017-06-01 12:44:08.813 MenuBar[2750:135123] the data Details is phone=9047038606
2017-06-01 12:44:08.829 MenuBar[2750:135123] 9047038606
2017-06-01 12:44:08.835 MenuBar[2750:135123]  storage:(null)
2017-06-01 12:44:08.836 MenuBar[2750:135123] tmp storage:(null)
2017-06-01 12:44:10.122 MenuBar[2750:135162] requestReply: {
otp = 552749;
success = 1; 
}
2017-06-01 12:44:10.122 MenuBar[2750:135162] tmp storage inside block:552749
```

Comment: `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` is async. Look carefully that `NSLog(@" storage:%@",self.str); NSLog(@"tmp storage:%@",self.tmp);` are printed BEFORE `NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);` and `NSLog(@"tmp storage inside block:%@",self.tmp);`. There are plenty of question about understanding/managing/handling async calls in SO ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

block is the additional thread , so you need to wait for completion block, so change your code like below

if you want to acces the data in outside

```
 - (IBAction)submitb:(id)sender
{
if (_mobiletf.text && _mobiletf.text.length >0 )
{
    /* not empty - do something */
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"phone=%@",_mobiletf.text];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    //  Next up, we read the postData's length, so we can pass it along in the request.
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    // Now that we have what we'd like to post, we can create an NSMutableURLRequest, and include our postData
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sitesandflats.com/send_otp.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSLog(@"the data Details is %@", post);
    //   And finally, we can send our request, and read the reply by creating a new NSURLSession:
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // this is json string
         //   NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
            NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);
            self.tmp=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"otp"] ;
            self.str=self.tmp;
            NSLog(@"tmp storage inside block:%@",self.tmp);

            [self updateStatus];

    }] resume];


}
else
{
    /* what ever */
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
        message:@"Please check your input!!."
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}

-(void)updateStatus{
NSLog(@" storage:%@",self.str);
NSLog(@"tmp storage:%@",self.tmp);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [ self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b1" sender:self];
});

 }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(nullable    id)sender
{
VerifyViewController *loadCtr = (VerifyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
loadCtr.otpStr =self.tmp;
loadCtr.mobileStr = _mobiletf.text;

}
```

Comment: yes but outside of the block the variable doesn't have the data!! it prints null actually I have to pass it to next controller I have done that part now I am nt able to access data out of this block

Comment: @akshay -blocks are called additionaly in main thread so we need to wait for completion , check the updated answer

Comment: still I am getting same result and I have performed segue inside coz it is a if else block to check for valid input else block produces alert view

Comment: @Anbu-ya I  understood that and still if I access thru second view controller the value is not passed I have to verify this value in second view controller

Comment: @akshay - your code is fine and correct, are you seen where i added this code `NSLog(@" storage:%@",self.str);
    NSLog(@"tmp storage:%@",self.tmp);
    [ self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b1" sender:self];`

Comment: @akshay - check the option 2 answer

Comment: yes I replaced and saw simulator gave me some error and app crashed!!

Comment: @akshay - what the crash report

Comment: @akshay  - are you seen my option 2 answer, i clearly answered

Comment: @akshay - can you update the question with latest answer, and where u faced the crash

Comment: sorry I jus now saw ur updated and let me try and let u know!!thank u for ur help

Comment: @akshay - ha ha ha, good i am waiting for your valuable reply

Comment: wen I click the submit button I am not able to move to next page segue is not performing it is inside the if block!!

Comment: @akshay - are you get the output in here `NSLog(@"tmp storage inside block:%@",self.tmp);` and here `NSLog(@"tmp storage:%@",self.tmp);`

Comment: nope I get only2017-06-01 13:21:38.907 MenuBar[2933:153569] the data Details is phone=9047038606
2017-06-01 13:21:40.751 MenuBar[2933:153616] requestReply: {
    otp = 451021;
    success = 1;
}
2017-06-01 13:21:40.751 MenuBar[2933:153616] tmp storage inside block:451021

Comment: there is no tmp storage printed

Comment: @akshay - add the break point in inside `-(void)updateStatus{` this method and check once the values are comes or not

Comment: I used break points and the code is not being executed which is outside the block it goes to resume and executes again

Comment: @akshay -can you attach the project i wull check

Comment: better I can mail it to u

Comment: @akshay - ok ,,

Comment: give me ur mailid